# Why am I getting ab ITMS-4238 "Redundant Binary Upload" error when submitting to the App Store?

Tags: xcode6, app-store, appstore-approval

I'm on Xcode 6, and I'm trying to submit an iOS (target: iOS 8) app to the App Store, and I'm getting an ITMS-4238 error. It says there is already the same build already, but I've never successfully submitted this app so far. So there is no submitted build in iTunes Connect, so I don't know why I'm getting this.

What I'm doing is following:

1. Create an Archive
2. Submit binary from Organizer

I also tried to submit with ApplicationLoader but the result was same.

This is the error I'm getting:

> **Archive submission failed with errors:**
>
> Archive submission failed due to the issues listed below:
>
> - ERROR ITMS-4238: "Redundant Binary Upload. There already exists a binary upload with build version '1.0' for train '1.0'" at SoftwareAssets/PreReleaseSoftwareAsset

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image: Screenshot for error]

Any ideas how to fix this?

**Progress:**
I solved my problem by myself.
I increased my build number from 1.0 to 1.0.2.1 .
I don't know why iTunes Connect thinks there is already binary version 1.0.

Comment: Had the same issue. Did Basheer's (and your) answer finally work?

Comment: Does anyone knows if i can just delete the contents of SoftwareAssets/PreReleaseSoftwareAsset? Where to find it anyway?

Comment: Real answer: because Apple doesn't care very much about the UX for devs. Presumably the (-) button next to the previously uploaded build that removes it visually, followed by pressing the Save button, should make Itunes Connect aware that the build is removed. But that doesn't seem to work very well at all.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try to increase the build number and submit the app. The version number can remain same. It worked for me :-)

Comment: Also, as a side note, increase by 1. So if you had 1.0, change it to 2.0. And do not forget to change it for iOS and for watchOS if you have one!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ApplicationLoader. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the info.plist in Xcode set your app version to the correct version in iTunes Connect. This worked for me to help update my app's version.